# PDOException in MySQL 5.7

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at
> line 1'

I'm trying to upgrade some code from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 and I'm not sure how to rewrite this?

```
    public function getPlayerInfo($uid){

        $this->session->newQuery();
        $sqlSelect = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, login, gameIP, homeIP, gamePass, email FROM users WHERE id = $uid LIMIT 1";
        $data = $this->pdo->query($sqlSelect)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if($data->total == 0){
            exit();
        }
```

To clarify what this does, it's supposed to return relevant player data, for example, further down in this file, I have:

```
if($doomStats['DOOM']['clanID'] == 0){
                    $doomedBy = '<a href="profile?id='.$doomStats['DOOM']['creatorID'].'">'.self::getPlayerInfo($doomStats['DOOM']['creatorID'])->login.'</a>';
                } else {
                    
                    $clan = new Clan();
                    $clanInfo = $clan->getClanInfo($doomStats['DOOM']['clanID']);
                    $doomedBy = '<a href="clan?id="'.$doomStats['DOOM']['clanID'].'">'.$clanInfo->name.'</a>';
                    $doomedBy .= ' <span class="small nomargin">(Released by <a href="profile?id='.$doomStats['DOOM']['creatorID'].'">'.self::getPlayerInfo($doomStats['DOOM']['creatorID'])->login.'</a>)</span>';
                }
```

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  In general, using parameters solves unexpected problems.

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This wasn't my intention as this project covers all of my tags. I apologize.

Comment: remove `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited the question with an example where this function is called.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `count` without an aggregate function? eg: `groupby` also put `$uid` in single quotes

Comment: omg so simple. Yes, thanks '$uid' shut MySQL up.
Also, GROUPBY would take everything by X and return only that value, so I can't use that here. Thank you for suggesting the single quote fix, as it worked!